# Падежные формы от "четвертьфинал"

Tags: грамматика

Здравствуйте! Ответьте,  пожалуйста,как правильно сказать: "Вышел в четвертьфинал или вышел в четвертьфинала?2

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: вышел в четвертьфинал (В.п.)

ЧЕТВЕРТЬФИНАЛ, -а; м. Спорт. Предшествующая полуфиналу игра на первенство, в которой участвуют восемь команд или игроков - победителей предшествующего круга соревнований. Выйти в ч. Встретиться в четвертьфинале (о встрече команд).

Четвертьфинал - неодуш. сущ., поэтому В.п совпадает с И.п.

Но: выйти в четверть финала. Это словосочетание, управление Р.п.

Comment: Все правильно, только имейте в виду, что как ***сочетание*** употребляется крайне редко. "В одну четвертую финала" еще слышал. "В четверть финала"  - нонсенс. Хотя грамматически, конечно, безупречно.

Comment: _behemothus: ...как сочетание употребляется крайне редко._ === Встречается и в учебниках:

_"Раскройте скобки. 1) (пол)чайной ложки, сидеть (впол)оборота, **выйти в (четверть)финала**"_.
https://books.google.ru/books?id=6cqyAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT100&dq=%22%D0%92+%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0CEQQ6AEwCGoVChMIh4H57MWPyQIVR6ZyCh3x-gD1#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%92%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%22&f=false

Comment: Идиоты, прости, Господи. Ну что делать, раз встречается, значит так тому и быть.))) Еще бы в "половину финала" написали. ))))) Спасибо, сдаюсь.

Answer (score 1):

> Вышел в четвертьфинал или вышел в четвертьфинала?

Здесь после предлога ***"в"*** нужен винительный падеж.

Возможны такие варианты:

***вышел в четвертьфинал,***

***вышел в четверть*** финала,

***вышел в одну четвертую*** финала.